# Android apps 64-bit support deadline pushed to 2020?

Tags: android, google-play, 64-bit

As we all know, starting August 1, 2019 all new apps and app updates that include native code [are required to provide 64-bit versions in addition to 32-bit versions](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html) when publishing to Google Play. This is was also stated [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/06/moving-android-studio-and-android.html) and [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/64-bit).

Yet some of our apps' Google Play listings begin to display the following message when uploading a 32-bit only version:
[image]
The *learn more* link leads to the first link I've provided.

So was the deadline indeed extended to February 1, 2020? Is this extention for specific apps only? I have found nothing about this on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We reached out to Google for clarification and received the following response:

> Your app will not be removed after the deadline for 64-bit compliance in February.
>
> However, once the deadline has passed, you will not be able to upload updates that don't support 64-bit versions of any 32-bit platforms supported by your app.

Our specific app received the February submission extension because we were partially supporting 64-bit. We had previously submitted x86_64 but not arm64-v8a.

Comment: The fact that the app will not be removed isn't new. But Google seems to corroborate the February time extension, which is extremely important.

Answer (score -1):

It is a different deadline, so it was not extended. if you make an update right now it needs to include 64-bit support, but your app is still available on play store. So i assume february 2020 the app will be removed from play-store and no longer available for download unless you have provided an update that includes 64-bit support.

Comment: I cant find any links supporting your statement. Also [it seems to contradict Google's own words](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html), which state that Google Play will only stop serving 32-bit apps on 64-bit devices **starting August 1, 2021**.

Comment: sorry i should have been clearer, i know for a fact that the deadline have not been pushed, because my apps was forced 64 bit when released last week. I can not find any reference to the date february 1st, but based onthe message i can only assume that this means your app will deactivated if you do not supply a 64 bit version by this time. Perhaps the final date for your specific app is based on when your lastest version was uploaded.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the link i've provided stating August 1, 2021 as the date Play would stop serving 32-bit? Also - this message appears across several apps. Albeit - all of them were first submitted long before 2019.

Comment: As i understand it august 1 2021 is the complete final deadline, meaning at this point there will be no apps without 64bit support available on play store without any exceptions. in the 2019 august deadline there were several exceptions, for example unity, which will probably have individual deadlines for requiring new updates to include 64bit and being removed from playstore, and 2021 is the absolute latest that an app will be removed from play store for not including 64 bit support.